# Использование валидатора ввода в PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, меню, валидация

Хочу в своем проекте использовать `PreferenceActivity` для создания меню настроек приложения.
Чтобы проще изложить суть впроса, приведу [урок на стартандроид](http://www.startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom) (урок 71):

> Если запустить этот проект и перейти в преференсах к вводу опции
>   Address,то появляется встроенный диалог с двумя кнопками ("Отмена",
>   "Ок") и полем для ввода текста.

Я хочу перехватить введенный пользователем текст при нажатии баттона `Ок`, проверить текст (в моем случае это задается пароль и вводится e-mail) и если этот текст не соответствует определенным условиям, то выдать юзеру какой-то notification и не сохранять введенное значение при нажатии `Ок` пока юзер не введет корректный текст или не нажмет `Отмену`. Нету никакого доступа к этому встроенному диалогу.
Я нашел callbacks которые отслеживают изменение настроек уже по факту сохранения текста в преференсах (`OnPreferenceChangeListener`, `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`). Но есть ли возможность использовать какой-то валидатор ввода юзером до сохранения введенного юзером текста?

Comment: Для решения возникшей проблемы мне пришлось создать кастомное окно настроек с использованием DialogFragment, AlertDialog.Builder() и переопределением лисенера для  Ок, так как это описано здесь:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620444/how-to-prevent-a-dialog-from-closing-when-a-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `OnPreferenceChangeListener`:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    findPreference("название_поля_конфигурации").setOnPreferenceChangeListener(
        new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            //newValue - новое значение. 
            //Проверьте его и верните true или false в зависимости от результата.
            //Можно также показать какое-нибудь окно с ошибкой.
        }

    });
  }
}
```

**Верните `false`, чтобы отменить сохранение нового значения, или `true`, чтобы подтвердить сохранение.**

Comment: интерфейс OnPreferenceChangeListener отслеживает изменение настроек уже по факту сохранения текста в преференсах и не дает возможности применить валидатор текста до его сохранения в преференсах. Кроме того, в Вашем листинге "implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener" в объявлении класса является лишним, так как этот интерфейс объявлен и реализован непосредственно в теле класса.

Comment: @Vitaliy отредактировал, так должно быть понятней. Не заметил `implements ..`, убрал.